# Leave Off Quickly, a short riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

```
Can I get your attention,
With what Jessie does mention,
Your hair that never stays stuck.

A life who hard knocks,
When you slip on your socks,
And end all roughened up.

An intimate meeting,
An abrupt harsh feeling,
And all for just one buck.
```

What's the word that's been keeping me up?

**Hint 1**

> Jessie is the first name of a singer, and the line is referencing a song. But again, it's not necessary to solve this riddle.

**Hint 2**

> "What's the word that has been keeping me up?" Is 100% true, it inspired this riddle.

Comment: Your riddles seem like good candidates for [`rhyme`](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhyme) tagging

Comment: Is it remotely linked with Breaking Bad !?

Comment: @humn didn't notice that tag, will do. And not the right Jessie ;)

Comment: Should this have the [tag:knowledge] tag?

Comment: Mentioned a person's name in one line but it's not needed to solve the riddle. Each line makes reference to the word in its own way. Each line can be taken separately. But I can add it if you feel its needed.

Comment: Hmm... does this involve time travel?

Comment: Nope! No time travelling shenanigans here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't figured out all the lines but is the word

> Bang

Can I get your attention,
With what Jessie does mention,
Your hair that never stays stuck.

> A Bang will get your attention. 
> Jessie J had a song Bang Bang with Ariana Grande and Nicki Minaj.
> Bangs are a style of hair cut.

A life who hard knocks,
When you slip on your socks,
And end all roughened up.

> A bang is a hard knock 
> Banged-up is synonymous to roughened-up.

An intimate meeting,
An abrupt harsh feeling,
And all for just one buck.

> Bang is a slang term for intimacy
> Getting the best Bang for your buck is a popular saying.

Its probably keeping you up because

> Someone or something is making a banging sound at night.  Possibly stormy weather.

Comment: You are correct! Finish addressing each line and the ttile and then I'll mark it as correct. Well done. And that's right @humn ;)

Comment: Still working on the other lines and title.  If someone can complete the puzzle, feel free to run with it.

Answer (score 3):

Could the answer be...

> shot?

*Can I get your attention,

With what Jessie does mention,

Your hair that never stays stuck.*

> Having a hard time here, possibly related to "give it a shot"? "Shot in the dark"?

*A life who hard knocks,

When you slip on your socks,

And end all roughened up.*

> Something that is 'shot' is broken, useless, or rough. A 'shot' life, and maybe you slip and your knees get 'shot'

*An intimate meeting,

An abrupt harsh feeling,

And all for just one buck*

> Probably the closest fit: intimate meeting would be the stock to the shoulder. Abrupt, harsh feeling would be recoil/kick. All for just one buck-- deer hunting.

Title

> Leave off quickly: off like a shot

Clearly not all correct, but perhaps someone else can fill in the blanks.

Comment: On the right track with your train of thought, but that's not it

Comment: I will say you are pretty warm though.

Answer (score 2):

What's the word that's been keeping me up?

> alert — i.e. an alarm is a form of an alert

This is not the correct answer:

> it is probably a much more metaphorical answer to the question above — not the thought of the word, but the thought with the word.

Nevertheless, here were my interpretations:

> Can I get your attention,
>
> > to **alert** someone
>
> With what Jessie does mention,
>
> > “Jessie” is the name of a Debian iteration; Debian is an OS; an **alert** is a common feature of the graphical user interface.
>
> Your hair that never stays stuck.
>
> > someone on **alert**, i.e. being watchful to danger, tends to have hair that stands on end — cats and dogs, e.g., but humans too.  Especially if that danger frightens them, of course.
>
> A life who hard knocks,
>
> > you knock on a door to **alert** someone when you are calling.
>
> When you slip on your socks,
> And end all roughened up.
>
> > an archaic use of of the word **alert**:  “Brisk; nimble; moving with celerity.”  (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alert#Adjective)
>
> An intimate meeting,
>
> > an **alert** guard is usually nearby whatever is being guarded.
>
> An abrupt harsh feeling,
>
> > an **alert** is usually harsh, especially if it comes unexpectedly.
>
> And all for just one buck.
>
> > ‘**alert**est’ is a so–called “[one–dollar word](https://mathlair.allfunandgames.ca/onedollarwords.php)”:  a word with a numerological value equal to 100.  The word ‘alert’ is $1+12+5+18+20=56$, and $56+5+19+20=100$.

Comment: That may fit some of the lines, but it doesn't fit others. I wouldn't describe alert as a harsh feeling or an intimate meeting. I'll add a hint about Jessie

Comment: @PaigeMeinke Oh, okay.  Well, I guess I should add what I _thought_ was the interpretation for those lines — though it is not the correct answer.

Comment: I do like your answer, but a few are that are a little reaching, for example, I chose the word intimate over other words on purpose. Alertest, didn't know about that word, but that's pretty darn cool. You are on the right train of thought too.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the word is ...

> **Flip**

```
Can I get your attention,  
With what Jessie does mention,  
Your hair that never stays stuck.
```

> Jessie James Decker has a new (unreleased?) song named "**Flip** My Hair", which is something women sometimes do to attract attention.  Hair that never stays stuck seems a pretty clear reference to this.

```
A life who hard knocks,  
When you slip on your socks,  
And end all roughened up.
```

> You might well slip on your socks and **flip** head over heels, ending all roughed up in the ensuing fall.

```
An intimate meeting,  
An abrupt harsh feeling,  
And all for just one buck.
```

> I'm not sure what is intended here.

Comment: I like the interpretation of the hair line, but yeah it doesn't quite fit the last stanza.